# Chromium won't load any websites and keeps crashing

Tags: chromium, puppeteer

All of the sudden my scripts aren't working anymore.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://www.google.com");

  // browser.close();
}

run();
```

When I run node index.js, Chromium launches, however, it is all white, then my mouse turns into the little rainbow spinning circle (Mac) and it crashes and I get the following error:

```
(node:37226) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on mac and solved it by adding `'--no-sandbox'` to the chrome args.

You can expose it as an env variable like so:

```
CHROME_ARGS=--no-sandbox
```

or add it to your `browser.launch` configuration:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false, 
  args: ['--no-sandbox']
});
```